# Why am I getting â€ character in plain HTML?

Tags: html, unicode, html-encode

I have bound data to a repeater control in ab asp.net application. When the data is displayed in plain HTML text in the browser it comes with these characters: â€. I am unable to figure out the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

have you given this in your code?

http://ask-leo.com/why_do_i_get_odd_characters_instead_of_quotes_in_my_documents.html

Comment: I didnt specify a meta tag with charset in any of my page. As read in many articles UTF-8 is default for every web document. I am clueless why the page pops up with such characters. Thanks to your code and it helped. Can you explain why its not recognizing default charset?

Comment: It made no sense that this worked for you, your data was UTF-8 being interpreted in CP1252. So if anything would have worked, it would have been `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`, **not** this answer

Answer (score 4):

What kind of html document type are you writing right now. If it's HTML 5, then check if you have `<meta charset=utf8 />` under the `<head>` tag. If you are using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />` under your `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the tables in the database to see what collation they are eg latin1_swedish_ci, utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Use symbol " . Do not use ”

Correct example:

```
<a href="http://www.mozilla.com">mozilla.com</a>
```

Incorrect:

```
<a href=”http://www.mozilla.com”>mozilla.com</a>
```